# what does mean Open Transaction and Commit Transaction

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm working on neo4j . now I faced with two window : `Open Transaction` and `Commit Transaction` .

what does mean `Open Transaction` and `Commit Transaction` ?

picture of neo4j:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neo4j browser used the [Transactional Cypher HTTP endpoint](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/http-api/#http-api-transactional) to execute your Cypher query.

The browser first opened a transaction (in the "Open Transaction" phase) by making a request to that endpoint *without passing a Cypher statement*.

It then committed that transaction (in the "Commit Transaction" phase) by making a second request to that endpoint (with the appropriate numeric transaction id), passing your Cypher statement.

Answer (score 0):

By `Open Transaction` you will be opening a new transaction and by `Commit Transaction` you will be saving the changes to the transaction you were working upon